# How can i remove standard objects from salesforce1 navigation Menu

Tags: salesforce1-app

Hi i am trying to build a salesforce1 app with all custom objects/tabs . Can i remove standard tabs like accounts/contacts... objects from navigation ??

Is it possible to remove salesforce1 standard tabs??

I am having second question:
I am using a complete new layout page which is designed using vf page and i added it to button(tab/view page) but in salesforce1 i am not getting standard pages. Can i override new vf page in salesforce1 for standard objects??

Answer (score 1):

> Hi i am trying to build a salesforce1 app with all custom objects/tabs
>   . Can i remove standard tabs like accounts/contacts... objects from
>   navigation ??
>
> Is it possible to remove salesforce1 standard tabs??

You can remove tabs like "Today" and "Tasks" by using Setup > Mobile Configuration > Mobile Navigation, but Accounts and Contacts can only be removed by removing the user's ability to view those objects/tabs entirely. Those tabs naturally move towards the top as the user uses these tabs, so the app customizes itself for each user based on their usage.

> I am having second question: I am using a complete new layout page
>   which is designed using vf page and i added it to button(tab/view
>   page) but in salesforce1 i am not getting standard pages. Can i
>   override new vf page in salesforce1 for standard objects??

Yes, but the Visualforce page must be marked as "available for salesforce mobile apps", or it won't override the page. You can view this setting by editing the page in the browser, or by viewing its property file in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

**Anything represented by a tab in Salesforce—such as standard and custom objects, Visualforce pages,
the Chatter feed, People, or Groups—is visible for a user in the Salesforce1 menu, based on the user’s
profile settings. For example, if a user is assigned to a profile that has the Groups tab set to Tab Hidden,
the user won’t see the Groups menu item in Salesforce1, even though an administrator has included
it in the menu.**

---

- Configuring the Salesforce1 Navigation Menu

---

From Setup, enter Navigation in the Quick Find box, then select Salesforce1 Navigation.
Some items are automatically added to the menu.

[image]